# Get data from url in android

Tags: php, android, json, url

I want to get data from url. in this case I've got complete php that data convert to json already and run in localhost (http://localhost/adchara1/index.php/?year=1)

This is the php script

```
<?php
 mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
 mysql_select_db("test");
 $q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people
 WHERE
 birthyear>'".$_REQUEST['year']."'");
 while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
         $output[]=$e;
   print(json_encode($output));
   mysql_close(); ?>
```

and this is result

```
[{"id":"1","name":"kongkea","sex":"1","birthyear":"1990"}, {"id":"2","name":"thida","sex":"0","birthyear":"2000"}]?>
```

I want to use button click and show this result in textview

Comment: actually what do u want to  ask ?android code for same or u have any doubt?

Comment: in android, I want to get the url from result to show in textView in android. ex, In android I have 1button and 1 TextView, I want to get the result in url `[{"id":"1","name":"kongkea","sex":"1","birthyear":"1990"}, {"id":"2","name":"thida","sex":"0","birthyear":"2000"}]?>` to show in TextView.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> mTask;
String jsonString;

String url = "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=50cent&count=2";


Button b;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFetch);
    final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView);

    mTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> () {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                jsonString = getJsonFromServer(url);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            tv.setText(jsonString);

        }

    };

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mTask.execute();
        }
    });
}


public static String getJsonFromServer(String url) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader inputStream = null;

    URL jsonUrl = new URL(url);
    URLConnection dc = jsonUrl.openConnection();

    dc.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    dc.setReadTimeout(5000);

    inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            dc.getInputStream()));

    // read the JSON results into a string
    String jsonResult = inputStream.readLine();
    return jsonResult;
}

}
```

After Getting jsonString from server with this method, you can parse and show the data in the Json.

EDIT: You get error because you are trying to get json from server out of async task.You need to do it in the background. You can either use a thread or use AsyncTask.

Comment: thanks for answer but it doesn't work. here your code. [code](http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?15vdw54ct84zeqv)

Comment: thanks. it works. i use button to clear textview(tv.setText("")). and get data again but error. y?

Answer (score 5):

Write this code in your Button OnClickListener

```
        try {
        String url = "http://YourIPAddress/adchara1/index.php/?year=1";
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        try {
            HttpParams p = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(p);
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost,
                    responseHandler);
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(responseBody);
            String text="";
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject e = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    text = text + "ID : "+e.getString("id")+"\n";
                    text = text + "Name : "+e.getString("name")+"\n";
                    text = text + "Sex : "+e.getString("sex")+"\n";
                    text = text + "Birthyear : "+e.getString("birthyear")+"\n";
            }
            Textview.setText(text);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Request failed: " + t.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If you have any clarifications notify me

Comment: Thanks for answer but it doesn't work. [Project](http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?5g12g4hs0ngnasl). thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Button button =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        TextView tv =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String result = connectionFromServer("http://localhost/adchara1/index.php/?year=1");
                tv.setText(result);
            }
        });   

 public static String connectionFromServer(String url) throws IOException {

            BufferedReader inputStream = null;

            URL myurl = new URL(url);
            URLConnection dc = myurl.openConnection();

            dc.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            dc.setReadTimeout(5000);

            inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    dc.getInputStream()));

            // read the JSON results into a string
            String result = inputStream.readLine();
            return result;
        }
```

This will display result in textview.

Comment: thanks for answer but it doesn't work. here is your code [http://www.mediafire.com/?as4kuid2iots4bx]

Answer (score 0):

You should simply do a get request using HttpClient and turn the string into Json Array, using the JSONArray object.

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html

Comment: I try to do this in alot of tutorial and it doesn't work so I decide to ask. can you complete this code