# How do I Connect an android application to a running MySQL Database, on an external hosted server

Tags: php, android, mysql, apache, wamp

Basicly, i've been doing a lot of searching around and still haven't found anything that solves the issue.

I am trying to connect my application to a database that is ran and hosted by a company, on an external server (we already use this database for a application we run on users computers)

I want to query the database for a login, so that when a user enters in his username and password on my app, it will compair these details with the details in the database, and reply back, stating if these credentials are correct, or not, and allowing the user to see a different page which will pull specific details from the database for that user (but thats something i need to solve in the future)

my main issue at the moment, is I cant seem to get the app to be able to connect to the database, currently I am using a WAMP server to host a php file I made...

NOTE: i will be using "user" and "pass" instead of the actual username and password I have

```
<?php

//connecting
//server, username, password, database

$dbhost = 'external ip entered here';
$dbuser = 'user';
$dbpass = 'pass';
$dbdb   = 'datbasename';

//connect to mySQL 
$connect = mysql_connect ($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass) or die("Connection error");

//select the database
mysql_select_db($dbdb) or die ("database selection error");

//Retrieve the login details via POST
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

//Query the table
$query="SELECT llogint,lpasint FROM TCHAUFF (nolock) 
WHERE llogint='$username' AND lpasint='$password'";

//check if there any results returned
$num = mysql_num_rows($query);

//if a record was found matching the details entered in the query
if($num == 1){
//create a while loop that places the returned data into an array
while($list=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

//store the returned data into variable
$output = $list;

//encode the returned data in JSON format
echo json_encode( $output );
//close the connection
mysql_close();
}}
?>
```

I don't think theirs any issue with the php file to be honest but please correct me if so haha!

the problem i'm having is if I try and run this php file from WAMP by placing the file into the www folder and going to localhost/androidtest.php

I get an error saying Warning: mysql_connect(): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

I have tried literally every solution i could find,

added this information to the config.inc.php file

```
/* Server: UserSeaCogi[1] */
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'external database';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'external ip entered here';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'user';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'pass';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

I'm lost for ideas!

i have added 
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
to the my.ini file

but am thinking its something to do with the way i have WAMP setup, but I cant seem to find what to change.

I also know I definitely have access to the database, as I can run querys from it if I add it to visual studio...one thing to note..it is a 2003 server...i know that had certain limitations with visual studio not sure about with android?

Thanks in advance

Comment: A possible solution to your woes - http://stackoverflow.com/a/12347949/1248938

Answer (score 0):

In your php code

```
mysql_select_db($dbdb)
```

should be

```
mysql_select_db($dbdb,$connect) ;
```

Then add these lines

```
$result = mysql_query($query, $connect);
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: By network IP do you mean my IP? the IP of the database i'm trying to connect to or my external IP?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply/edit ive added the lines in and changed that but am still left with the same error, this is frustrating! haha!